Java / Python Copy data between 2 databases
I have use case of copying data of 10 tables data from Prod to 3 lower environments, both are oracle databases. Can use Spring boot Or Python.Started with Springboot(Java) which i am more comfortable with. But number of domain entity objects, rowmapper/Resultset extractor and then Batchpreparedstatementsetter, multiples number of java files i need to create for each table.
Since Prod and Lower environment have the same table structure is there any easy way to copy data?
Domain/Entity Object
@Entity
@Table(name="COUNTRY_REGN", schema = "DUSK")
public class CountryRegion {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ISO_COUNTRY_ID")...

ResultSetExtractor
public class CountryRegionResultSetExtractor implements ResultSetExtractor<List<CountryRegion>> {
    @Override
    public List<CountryRegion> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        List<CountryRegion> countryRegionList= new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            CountryRegion countryRegion = new CountryRegion();
            countryRegion.setIsoCountryId(rs.getLong("iso_country_id"));

Then finally Select, Delete and Insert. jdbcTemplateToSync - will be initialized based on the input param, like DEV/UAT..
List<CountryRegion> dataList = prodJdbcTemplate.query("select * from COUNTRY_REGION", new CountryRegionResultSetExtractor());
        jdbcTemplateToSync.update("DELETE FROM COUNTRY_REGION");
        
        jdbcTemplateToSync.batchUpdate("""
                       Insert into COUNTRY_REGION (ISO_COUNTRY_ID........) values
                       (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                       """,
               dataList,
               100,
               (PreparedStatement ps, CountryRegion countryRegion) -> {
                   ps.setLong(1, countryRegion.getIsoCountryId());
                   .....;
               });

I need to repeat this process for all 10 tables, is there easy way to do this?

Create a database link between the two databases and insert directly from one database to the other. Don't use another language.

Or if you can't create a DB link (which may not be allowed, particularly between prod/non-prod), use data pump to export and import.

And if datapump isn't practical for some reason, don't re-invent the wheel. Open source software like Apache NiFi can be used to migrate data, too.

@AlexPoole DB Link is not an option/not allowed. Going ask my arch team if Apache Nifi can be used
